# How do I exclude categories from promotions on OpenCart?

Tags: opencart

We have thousands of products so for us excluding a category from the promotion is much faster than adding the categories to the promotion one by one. Problem is there is no way to exclude certain products from the promotion.

Is there a piece of code within OpenCart that could simply be changed so that the categories that are chosen to be part of the promotion are actually excluded instead?

I hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: are you doing this with a module or what? give us more detail

Comment: No, I'm using the stock coupon code programming. I haven't touched it. I just need a way to exclude one category. I don't care if I have to hard code something.

To explain a little better we have products that have MAP prices and they cannot be discounted using a coupon code. I am going to put these products into a 'hidden' category and that category will be excluded from promotions.

Comment: Hmm,this will take quite abit of work to be honest it wont just work with some random copy and paste,atleast i can't think of anything right of the bat

Comment: Is there an easier way to add all categories to the selection box in the admin and then just remove that one category once all categories have been added?

Comment: You kind of lost me here on this question,can you ask it agian?

Comment: I did what I asked you and it didn't work. Ahhhh lol!

In short I just need a way to exclude a certain product from coupon promotions when its within a certain category even if it's part of other categories.

Comment: hmm..i believe this is doable with a little bit of mysql code,i will try to set a little text code for my self and get back at you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81977/discussion-between-smack-a-bro-and-innervisions).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension to exclude a product or products from a coupon:

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=17525

***Disclaimer***: *I am the author of the extension and I stand to make a whopping $10 from it's sale.*